# Delpi7, DBGrid выбрать произвольную ячейку

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

Как в DBGrid выбрать произвольную ячейку? Тем таких вроде полно, но там все делается через SelectedIndex, а мне надо просто получить значение из ячейки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо определится с терминологией. Просто *Выбрать* читается как установить в интерфейсе.

А получить текущее выбранное поле можно через свойство `SelectedField`, т.е. само значение `DBGrid.SelectedField.Value`.

Если в опциях DBGrid будет установлено `dgRowSelect`,  то в свойстве будет поле первой колонки.